# iOS Copy documents and data when app purchased with a different Apple Id

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone where i downloaded a free app as Apple Id 1.

I have now logged out of Apple Id 1 on this device.

I need to update the app as it complains that it is too old to connect to a remote service.

I logged in with Apple Id 2.

When i try to update the app, device is asking for password for Apple Id 1.

I do not have access to Apple Id 1 anymore.

I tried offloading the app, but now when i try restoring it, iOS is still asking for password for Apple Id 1.

Since it is my understanding that there is no way to 'transfer purchases' to another Apple Id, i thought maybe there is a way to backup app's documents folder and keychain and then restore them somehow?

Comment: "do not have access to Apple Id 1" Why? The answer to that might change what you need to do.

Comment: I just don't. I don't have access to that e-mail, i can't reset that password, i just don't have access to it and i can not get in touch with whoever does have it now.

Comment: So… it's not your account & not a family member? Then it may depend entirely on whether the particular app can export its data.